# Xcode Textfield Save list

Tags: ios

I'd like to create an app where there are some textfield. When the user fills them and taps the "Save" button, the text will be saved in a local database. When the user wants, tapping on the "Load" button, the text previously saved will reappear.
Well, I've already made an app like this but I want to insert a sort of "list" of saved texts; with this, the user will be able to choose which screen reload of his own choice and not necessarily the last one. Can you help me to do this please? I hope you understand what I'd like to do.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: means you are trying like no of users data and you want to retrieve particular user data like that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add one more value into you dataBase, I guess I used CoreData, and she into this value  information about "What this texts are, and where I need to load it" or about smth else.
Then you can give the choice for user, which text hi need to load, and take it from coreData with predicates.

Comment: Yes, I think I want something like this. When the user chooses one of the saved files, the texts on the screen will set like at the time of saving. So must I use CoreData? How?

Comment: And How have you saved your texts before? Yes, if i was doing the same project I would use CoreData

Answer (score 0):

I think you should save the text along with the screen no when a user select any screen by clicking the load button then you fetch the data from the data base and then set it on the text field.

Answer (score 0):

Well I will try to answer you as per I have understand your question first you save all the data in database and then as you have said user  preferred reload only so put load button besides the text filed and when user press that button then only fitch that data from the database and display it over there and again if user will change it and then click again then our database will get changed.

you can user sqlite for inserting and selecting data from database i will advice you to use sqlite if you are beginner. stuff are available on internt how to do this all with sqlite hop this help